# SKAction play sound not from begining

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I want to play sound not from the beginning of the mp3 file, but from 14s after beginning. I have the following code for sound playing, but i was not successful in finding the solution:

```
if let textAudio = textAudio {
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1)
        let play = SKAction.play()
        if view.scene! == scene02 {
            // play 14s after begining
        }
        textAudio.run(SKAction.sequence([wait, play]))
    }
```

Comment: You can't do that with SKAction to my knowledge.

Comment: You need to use `SKAudioNode` with `AVAudioPlayerNode` if you want to stick with the `SpriteKit` framework.  Writing an answer for this would take way too long, and I do not know of any tutorials explaining this mechanic, perhaps somebody else will be able to add to this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AVAudioPlayer` and the `currentTime` method as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1387297-currenttime):

```
import AVFoundation
var textAudio: AVAudioPlayer?
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example.mp3", ofType:nil)!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {
    textAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    textAudio?.currentTime = TimeInterval(14.0)
    textAudio?.play()
} catch {
    // couldn't load file :(
}
```